# How to set dates to locale in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-date-format

So i have an angular application (angular 8) that will be used by the UK, Mauritius and South Africa (potentially more as well).

How can I set the dates be based on the locale of the users?

Will I use a custom pipe? Or set it as some sort of provider in the app.module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I make use of [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library, and would create a pipe to format the date in the desired language, e.g.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
    name: 'customdate'
})
export class CustomDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() { }

    transform(value: any, lng:string) {
            return moment(value).lang(lng).format("MMM");
        
    }
}
```

So e.g.

{{item.date | customdate : 'en-us'}}  = **March**

{{item.date | customdate : 'de'}}  = **März**

{{item.date | customdate : 'es'}}  = **Marzo**

Comment: Usually I would as well but I need to pick up the locale of the user's browser and have a generic Date() object that will set it based on that.

Answer (score 1):

In `app.module` I set the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` value like this:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'ro-RO' },  //YOUR DESIRED LOCALE
    DatePipe
  ],
```

Also, in other controls like `mat-table` I use pipes:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="alignLeft"> {{ element.Date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }}
```

When the content is dynamic you can try to use this:

```
import { LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(
  @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string
) { }
```

and send it as parameter to a custom pipe or other relevant method.

Let me know if that worked for you

Comment: Yeah that's similar to how I'm currently doing it, but if the user is in UK they need to see MM/dd/yyyy but SA must see it as yyyy/MM/dd.

Comment: @AustinReid I've updated my answer. hope it's what you were looking for

Comment: I think I'm still a little confused as to how the application will set the date . Could you perhaps please share a plunkr or if there's a repo I can check?

Comment: @AustinReid I don't have an example now but I suggest giving it a try using a browser vpn to change country and log the returned locale.
https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID

Comment: I am now struggling with this, You should be able to tell angular to infer the LOCALE_ID from the users browser. It doesn't make sense that you have to make it part of the bootstrap. That is no good for apps that will be used across different locales